# Jquery scripts in angularjs project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am working on angularjs project that I generated using yeoman angular generator.

I have a jQuery function that I need to use in most of my html views. 
A possible solution is to add this function to a script.js file for example, and add this file as reference in the html views that require this function. However, I don't think this solution is good.

When yeoman generates an angularjs project, in its index.html file, it adds a section

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
```

within this section, the different script files are added since as I think, on build, those files will be unified in a single scripts/scripts.js file.

I tried to do the same by adding the function to a script file, and added the reference of the this script file to this section. The problem is that the function is not working when I try to call it from any view.

What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

DOM manipulation is done with directives in angularjs you will need to check out the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

If you are not manipulating the DOM you can create a service that can be injected into any controller. 
Services documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

from there you can assign a function in the controller to the scope that can be accessed in the view. e.g.

```
$scope.MyFunction = function(){
    // Code goes here
}
```

you can call the function in the html as

```
<div ng-click="MyFunction()"></div>
```

Comment: Dear, seems you didn't understand the question. You are telling me about angularjs basics that I already know. I am asking about a sophisticated thing regarding script tags containing jQuery functions not angularjs content.

Comment: jquery functions won't work like that with angular from my experience. you need to use a directive or a service.

Comment: asin the scripts are not registered as part of the angular module