# Displaying pre-formatted html content retrieved from JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I have a pre-formatted HTML content in a JSON file

```
<p>This is <b>a formatted</b> <i>content</i></p>
```

as follows:

```
{
 "description" : "<p>This is <b>a formatted</b> <i>content</i></p>"  
}
```

I retrieved this content, and I want to display it formatted (a paragraph with bold and italic content). However, it is displayed same as it is.

I tried to use jquery using `$(this).html()`, and I tried to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>` but nothing worked!

Here is an example on plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/S1U9TdsMOj4XFUQkbz1X?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need a couple of things to make it work:

[**HERE**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OrDt7b5RDo34fl9yV0FA?p=preview) is forked working copy of your code

1. You need reference to `angular-sanitize.js` and `angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);`
2. Adding additional filter `trustHtml` which is using [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)
3. Using `ng-html-bind` inside your `news.html` template and applying the filter like this - `<h2 ng-bind-html="news.description | trustHtml"></h2>`

Comment: I don't know if there is a simpler solution, but the one you provided is working perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @EddyG here is another solution without creating custome filter just using `$sce` inside `NewsController` but I think the first one is better -> http://plnkr.co/edit/MrbVGWd6mBbwZo6qxlxw?p=preview

Comment: I agree with you. Since the first solution allows code reuse. I hope you can check a question I added earlier and I didn't get an answer for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935319/jquery-scripts-in-angularjs-project

Comment: I'd only recommend being more specific with the filter-name, since `$sce` can trust different things but this filter is specific for html. imo `news.description | rawHtml` would be more descriptive.

Comment: @Thomas I agree on this and made the necessary changes